# "the lady's thumb" or "lady's thumb"

Tags: grammar, modifiers

According to the encyclopedical manner (and what COBUILD advises too), we should put an article, be it definite or indefinite, before the name of a plant.

*A rose is a plant… The coconut tree is a member of… etc.…*

But when it comes to common names which include **Saxon genitive**, the problem seems to be complicating…

I do not consider the following webpage as a reliable reference, but they keep omitting adding articles to the plant called commonly as **"Lady's Thumb"**.

---

https://www.farms.com/field-guide/weed-management/ladys-thumb.aspx

---

Please, folks, help, as I would also opt for **no article**, but, all the same, I would write **the** burro's tale. Lady's eardrops or the lady's eardrops?

What I am aiming at is to get rather an informative register than a colloquial or common one.

Comment: Why would you treat it different from "crabgrass"?

Comment: A tricky example, as I would treat it as grass which is **uncountable** and, then, dismisses any article...

Comment: Her's an Encyclopedia Britannica entry:

**One well-known species is the yellow lady's slipper (Cypripedium calceolus); another is the pink lady's slipper (C. acaule), also known as the moccasin flower.**

Comment: But those are qualified with "pink".

Comment: Don't get me that I enjoy hurling quotes at you, but here's the Independent: **Now the lady's slipper has been saved in Britain, because seedlings have been planted out at 16 new sites, and have flowered at 11 of them**
OR
**My audience with a rare orchid In mystique, there is only one other flower in the whole of the British flora with which the ghost orchid, Epigogium aphyllum, can be compared, and that is another orchid species – the lady's slipper.**

It confused me like nothing else for a long time...

Comment: You need to understand that the use of the article or not in these situations is very much a "matter of opinion", but, beyond that, it often depends on whether the reference is to the item as a generic or as an archetype.

Comment: I get your point which is really helpful :) I might need someone to have told me that _expressis verbis_. That was my guess, too, that it was "a matter of opinion". Thank you for your time and patience ;) Case closed

Comment: You are quite right in claiming that some multi-word compound names are often used without an article. This is not limited to those with a Saxon genitive ('Black-eyed Susan is a native of east Africa ...'; [[BBC Gardening](http://www.bbc.co.uk/gardening/plants/plant_finder/plant_pages/915.shtml)]) or even to open compounds (Bindweed (Convolvulus) is often called wild morning glory [[Gardening Knowhow](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/plant-problems/weeds/controlling-bindweed.htm)]).